# parsing integer array on JSONcpp

Tags: jsoncpp

I'm having trouble parsing integer arrays using JsonCpp.
I am trying to read an array of integers from json input.
I'm getting the error:

> ambiguous overload for 'operator[]' in 'dataArray[0]'

I've tried:

```
Json::Value c_val;
const Json::Value dataArray = root["data"];
c_val = dataArray[0];   int a = c_val.asInt();
c_val = dataArray[1];   int b = c_val.asInt();
```

and I've also tried

```
int a = dataArray[0];
```

To no avail. Sample input json file:

```
{
 "data" : [ 1047, 140, 60, 60 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference:

Force integer input with '0u':

```
c_val = dataArray[0u];   int a = c_val.asInt();
```

solves it.